# Android can't read file system Samsung Galaxy S Captivate from my PC

Tags: android, file, usb, galaxy

My Samsung Galaxy S Captivate crashes on bootup and I need to read the log dump which is stored on the files system.  Problem is I cannot seem to see the phone as SD from my windows 7 PC.  I have USB connected which is good and can deploy to the phone an apk, but I cannot access the file system.  How do I access the file system on this phone.  Thanks

Comment: Odin 1.3 and Download mode are you friends with a borked Galaxy S phone!

Comment: what is your suggestion here?

Comment: Well it sounds like your phone is boot looping?? If so, you can get Odin here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10327745/Odin.7z You can find various recovery images around the internet, but using this + booting your phone into download mode you can fix it.

Comment: Nevermind, I just read your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331467/android-start-app-on-boot-from-broadcastreceiver-crashing I thought you meant it was boot looping before you got into the OS.

Comment: Well I just want to read something on the file system. How do I just read a log file?

Comment: I cannot access the file system. otherwise the phone is fine. How can I see files using keys? I tried switching to kies usb but still do not see /data/ etc

Comment: Actually I don't see the files system at all or the device from my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, and don't want to mount the SD every time (to keep debugging), you can do the following:[Window->Show view->other->android->file explorer / hierarchy view] (don't remember the exact name.)

Comment: just tried it and it says dump result is in /data/log/dump State_2001455.log but I everything upder /data is empty.  I see under file system  data, mmt but only sdcard, system and tmp seem to have values

Comment: well I did*#9900# then copy and I got a dumpState file transferred over to SD which is visible from files, but I am not seeing core dump error information here?

Answer (score 0):

Connect your phone to USB of your PC, on your phone, find and touch proper Notification message to mount SD card.

Comment: Logs are stored in /data/logs I according to output of *#9900# and I am not seeing these