# Android Start App On Boot from BroadcastReceiver Crashing

Tags: android, crash, boot

I am trying to start my Android 2.1 Galaxy S Phone on boot and it crashes.

Here is my receiver if I comment out context.startActivity(i) I don't get crash otherwise I see it on powerup.  startActivity from another activity using same ACTION does not cause crash. This seems to be just on Boot.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("DISPLAY_FIRSTPAGE");
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

I setup an receiver in the manifest like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
             android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
             android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Comment: Where it fails is the startActivity(i) somewhere. I am not able to see the crash log on my Samsung Galaxy Captivate to provide more info.

Comment: First you should start service and not activity.. Second You are trying it on ANDROID 2.1 ANCIENT device.. There is even hardly users available below 4.0; You should use alarm manager instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first look at the log before anything else.  In this case the problem (both with your original code and your fixed code) will be pretty clearly explained in the crash in the log.

Comment: Thats true. I'm on samsung captivate.  When core dump occurs it says that file is stored in /data/logs however this is not visible from eclipse android file viewer.  I see empty /data only sd and tmp seem to have files

Comment: I got a dump file but I did not see the core dump

Comment: @Androider: "The log" in this case is LogCat. Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace to find your error.

Comment: DALVIK THREADS:

  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.crash(RuntimeInit.java:368)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:887)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:884)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Ok. yes it is in the log after all.

Comment: The problem seems to be calling android startActivity() from outside Activity needs FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Answer (score 2):

You're clearly not telling it what to launch (unless you specify that your activity handles `DISPLAY_FIRSTPAGE` intents in the manifest, which wouldn't be a good idea). Try something along the lines of:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Tried this and I am still seeing the crash.

Comment: BTW Trying on emulator too and shutdown takes eons of time to test powerup. Is there any way to launch the emulator w/o starting an app.  Waiting for shutdown/startup takes forever

Comment: In my experience shutdown doesn't work on the emulator. Just close the window. As for launching it just run `emulator`. Or, if you prefer GUIs, use the Android SDK and AVD Manager, select an AVD and click Launch (or something similar).

Comment: Almost it needed FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK from when called from broadcast receiver.

Comment: Interesting. It means the context you're given is not Activity-capable, somehow. I find that peculiar, since I used to start `Service`s from `BroadcastReceiver`s like that without problems, so I imagined activities would be fine, too. Glad to see you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.startForegroundService(i);
    } else {
        context.startService(i);
    }
```